# How to modify a column of a csv in bash

Tags: bash, csv

Edit, this is how I modified the full file following the suggestions.
It's still not working as expected: the 4th column is printed as empty value in the stdout and the myCSV.csv is not altered by the applied function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function dec2ip() {
   local ip dec=$@
   for e in {3..0}
      do
         ((octet = dec / (256 ** e) ))
         ((dec -= octet * 256 ** e))
         ip+=$delim$octet
         local delim=.
      done
# printf '%s\n' "$ip"
}
dec2ip "$@"


decimal_subnets=( $(cut -d ',' -f4 /test/myCSV.csv ) )

echo ${#decimal_subnets[@]}

(
# print the header untouched
read line; echo "$line"
IFS=,
while read -ra fields; do
    fields[3]=$(dec2ip "${fields[3]}")
    echo "${fields[*]}" >> /test/myCSV_dotted.csv
done
) < /test/myCSV.csv
```

That's the output I see on the command line and the same content that appears in myCSV_dotted.csv (basically, the 4th column is "missing"):

```
VLAN ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,SUBNET
11,txt1,txt2,
12,txt3,txt4,
13,txt5,txt6,
```

Sample input is:

```
VLAN ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,SUBNET 
11,txt1,txt2,123456
12,txt3,txt4,789012
13,txt5,txt6,345678
```

It seems that the function `dec2ip()` is not providing the right result: what am I missing?

Comment: Show us your input (few lines of input csv) and expected output (in csv), rather than stating an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your requirement could be solved in much simpler way

Comment: suggestions: 1) http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 2) https://www.shellcheck.net/ 3) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice 4) use awk or perl/python with csv modules

Comment: @Inian: the input file is a list of IP addresses in decimal format, plus the heading (as shown above). The output, is the same file where the first line shouldn't be modified and the others should be converted into dotted format using the function "dec2ip"

Comment: @mlama: May I draw your attention to the first word of the first comment?

Comment: @Cyrus:

VLAN ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,SUBNET
11,txt1,txt2,123456
12,txt3,txt4,789012
13,txt5,txt6,345678

Comment: I modified the code as follows, but still I can't reach the result I'd expect:

decimal_subnets=( $(cut -d ',' -f4 /test/myCSV.csv ) )

subnets_length=${#decimal_subnets[@]}

for ((i=2;i<subnets_length+1;i++))
{
    dotted_subnets[$i]=dec2ip "${decimal_subnets[$i]}";
}

dotted_subnets should contain the converted IP in dotted format and should then be the basis to be used to overwrite the 4th column of myCSV.csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the version of the code that works, being `myCSV_new.csv`the output file with the 4th column properly modified:

```
dec2ip () {
local ip dec=$@
   for e in {3..0}
      do
         ((octet = dec / (256 ** e) ))
         ((dec -= octet * 256 ** e))
         ip+=$delim$octet
         local delim=.
      done
printf '%s\n' "$ip"
}

(
    # print the header untouched
    read line; echo "$line" >> /test/myCSV_new.csv
    IFS=,
    while read -ra fields; do
       fields[3]=$(dec2ip "${fields[3]}")
       echo "${fields[*]}" >> /test/myCSV_new.csv
    done
) < /test/myCSV.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( 
    # print the header untouched
    read line; echo "$line"
    IFS=,
    while read -ra fields; do 
        fields[3]=$(dec2ip "${fields[3]}")
        echo "${fields[*]}"
    done 
) < myCSV.csv
```

outputs

```
VLAN ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,SUBNET
11,txt1,txt2,0.1.226.64
12,txt3,txt4,0.12.10.20
13,txt5,txt6,0.5.70.78
```

Don't forget to make `delim` local in the dec2ip function

Comment: Thank you very much Glenn!
I modified my script according to your indications but I'm still stuck on it.

Comment: I should have uncommented "# printf '%s\n' "$ip"", now it works. Thanks again Glenn, your hint was more than useful!